# The variable is assigned but never used

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, variables

```
int i, j;
i = j = 1;
```

`j` is highlighted by VS 2010 with warning:

> The variable is assigned but never used

Why `i` is "used" and `j` - is not?

---

An addition with cooperation with Daniel:

```
int i, j, k, l, m;
i = j = k = l = m = 1;
```

Only `m` is highlighted.

Comment: To clarify, the steps to reproduce are (1) create a new Project of type Console application, and (2) add this code and nothing else inside the body of main.

Comment: This looks like an intellisense bug. By the way, I never knew you could use more than one `=`, I guess I never needed it :P

Comment: @Camilo: It's some kind C style of variables declaration/assignment

Comment: @Camilo: Incidentally, I'd never run across this warning, because by coding standards I'd declare _and_ initialize each variable in their own line.

Comment: @Daniel: Yea, my too. But my friend asked me, I saw it and decided to ask on SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's a bug, It should be in reverse order, **[`=` operator is a right precedent operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** according to Microsoft documentation. So when we have i = j = 1 it should parse it as i = (j = 1) in this case value of `j` used to initialize `i` so the compiler should say `i` initiated but never used, not `j`.

Answer (score 2):

Technically this should be the case for both `i` and `j`

**EDIT:**

I have again checked the code

```
int ii, jj;
ii = jj = 1;
```

using Reflector to generate IL I found

```
.maxstack 2
.locals init (
    [0] int32 ii,
    [1] int32 jj)
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: ldc.i4.1 //pushes the integer value of 1 onto the evaluation stack
L_0002: dup //copies the current topmost value on the evaluation stack, and then pushes the copy
L_0003: stloc.1 
L_0004: stloc.0 
L_0005: ret
```

From this, it would make it seem that 1 is assigned to ii, and then ii is *copied* to jj.

Comment: Yea, agree! So the questions is - does anybody have any suggestions why does it take place and not vice versa?

Comment: If you use Reflector on such a method, you will notice that the code gets optimized. The method body is empty. And also, Resharper shows the warning on both variables.

Comment: Isn't j used to assign i? If I assign a starting value to j I could for example do

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the Visual Studio C# compiler. We can't answer because we haven't implemented it.

---

**Original answer**

`i` is probably used later in your function, while `j` isn't.

To remove the "probably", you should post the whole function. (**Update:** This is not true. The whole code inside main is what the OP posted.)

Comment: This is only code. Try yourself :) Create a new console app and copy-paste the code there. The warning should appear

Comment: You are right. Actually, with "int i, j, k, l, m; i = j = k = l = m = 1;", only m is "assigned but never used".

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it with Resharper and it's smart enough to give warnings for all variables correctly.

Comment: Kudos to Resharper! These guys outperform the VS dev team sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is intended behaviour for `i` to not be highlighted as a warning, because it is initialised from the value of a variable. This warning is only ever given when the variable is assigned from a compile-time constant.

Try out the following code:

```
int i = 0;
string s = "string";
string t = "another string";
string u = t;
var v = new string('v', 1);
var y = new XElement("hello");
```

Only `i` and `s` are given warnings. According to [this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94167/cs0219-only-issued-on-constant-assignments-not-on-variables-or-return-values), this is intended (although for a rather questionable reason IMO).

So really the mystery here is why there are any warnings at all!

Answer (score -1):

I tried this on Visual Studio 2010 Professional and got no such warning. What flavour of VS2010 are you using? I use Professional at work and Express at home, and find the Express version less accurate with warnings.